# Creating a rolling standard deviation when in-between dates are not included in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, standard-deviation

I have daily transaction volumes and wanted to calculate the rolling 90 day standard deviation.  The issue is I don't necessarily have a row for dates with zero transactions.  For example, imagine I have the following 5 rows in a dataframe, which represents that there was 1 transaction for each day from 5/9/2021 - 5/13/2021:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# assuming I have 1 transaction that takes place on each day from 5/9/2021 - 5/13/2021
data = {'Date':['2021-05-09', '2021-05-10', '2021-05-11', '2021-05-12', '2021-05-13'],
        'Num_trans':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In order to calculate the rolling standard deviation for the past 90 days for each one, I'd need a complete dataframe with 90 days worth of data prior to each transaction.  Here's one way I could do this for this set:

```
#create list with 95 days and reverse it
numdays = 95
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]
date_strings = [d.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for d in date_list][::-1]


#convert to date string, and add column with 0 transactions, except for the last 5 dates
df2 = pd.DataFrame(date_strings,columns=['date'])
df2['num_trans'] = 0
df2.iloc[[90,91,92,93,94],[1]] = 1

#add in the rolling standard deviation for the previous 90 days
window_size=90
df2['std_prev_90_days'] = df2['num_trans'].rolling(window=window_size, min_periods=window_size).std().shift(1)
#the values in the std_prev_90_days are the intended output for each of the 5 transactions
df2.tail(5)
```

That would create an output like this, where the standard deviation values for each of these 5 transactions are what I'm trying to arrive at most efficiently (since I need to be able to do this on a rolling basis for millions of transactions).

[image: output standard deviations intended]

The necessary steps I'm looking to perform efficiently are:

1. Pull the daily transaction volumes for the previous 90 days
2. Fill in dates with no transactions with a count of zero
3. Calculate the rolling standard deviation as presented here.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this most efficiently?

Comment: kindly share your code, with the expected output as a dataframe

Comment: I've updated the question as per your request.  Hope that clarifies things.